Integration dashboard in Log Analytics
How do I create a dashboard looking like this in Log Analytics?

Logging schema is looking like this.
{
"correlationID": "An ID to correlate messages across the system",
"sourceComponent": "Component from message originates such as logic app name",
"subSourceComponent": "sub Component from message originates such as workflow name",
"executionID": "RunID",
"componentProperties": {        
    "source": "CustomerSite",
    "target": "D365FO",
    "data": "Debtor"
},
"businessKeys": 
{
    "debtorID": "debtor123",
    "uniqueID": "xxx-xxxx-xxx"
},
"success": false,
"einviornment": "Dev",
"failureMessages":
[
    { "message": "customer data is Invalid" }
],
"errorMessage": "customer data is Invalid", 
"aiMessage": "", 
"aiResolution": ""}

Can anyone give some hints on the query to aggregate the result and track a transaction handled by each component.
Regards,
Jonas

Have you checked this MSDoc. @Jonas K

Are you still facing the issue! @Jonas K

To create a dashboard for the given logging schema, firstly you need to write a KQL query in Azure with the corresponding fields.
Below is the sample query which you can use to create a dashboard for your logging schema. I have only included few fields for your reference purpose. Add all the fields based on your requirement.
<LogsTable>
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1d) 
| extend successTrans = tostring(parse_json(properties).sourceComponent),
         source = tostring(parse_json(properties).source),
         subsource = tostring(parse_json(properties).subsourceComponent),
| summarize TotalTrans = count(),
    SuccessTrans = countif(success == "true"),
    FailureTrans = countif(success == "false"),
    FailedMessages = make_list(failureMessages.message) by sourceComponent, subsourceComponent
| project source, subsource, TotalTrans,SuccessTrans,FailureTrans,FailedMessages
| order by TotalTrans desc

As I don't have your logs table in my environment, I have just run a sample query as shown below to let you know how the dashboard works exactly.
Once you are done with writing a query in Log analytics workspace, on the right top you can see save option as shown below. Click on the dropdown and you will be able to see the pin to Azure dashboard. Click on it and it will be pinned to the given dashboard.


If you don't have an existed one in the Azure Portal, Create a new dashboard and then pin the logs to it.
Refer MSDoc on creating and pinning it in a more detailed way.

Is the above one working for you. @Jonas K
